# what does the symbol [:] mean in Go?

Tags: go

I found this in some code:

```
h := s.Hash(tx)
sig, err := crypto.Sign(h[:], prv)
```

What does `[:]` mean ?
If this is the full slice of the array, why not to pass the array itself? What kind of coding style is this, I wonder...

Comment: It does take a slice of the full array ([as covered in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/10)), and you'd pass it instead of the full array to a function that accepts a slice, not an array. They aren't interchangeable.

Comment: One of the reasons of [:] is it allows you to convert from array to slice by creating a reference (slice) to the array's data without extra copy. If you'll just pass to function(method) an array you'll create a new copy of data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In go, Arrays and Slices are slightly different and cannot be used interchangeably; however, you can make a slice from an array easily using the `[:]` operator.

This article explains in detail - [Go Slices: Usage and Internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

See also the [Slice Expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) section of The Go Programming Language Specification.

In a nutshell, the `[:]` operator allows you to create a slice from an array, optionally using start and end bounds.  For example:

```
a := [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4} // "a" has type [4]int (array of 4 ints)
x := a[:]   // "x" has type []int (slice of ints) and length 4
y := a[:2]  // "y" has type []int, length 2, values {1, 2}
z := a[2:]  // "z" has type []int, length 2, values {3, 4}
m := a[1:3] // "m" has type []int, length 2, values {2, 3}
```

Presumably the reason for this distinction is for an extra measure of type safety. That is, length is a formal part of an array type (e.g. `[4]int` is an array of four ints and a different size is a different type) whereas slices can have any length, including zero. So if you want the safety of a known-length sequence then use an Array, otherwise use a Slice for convenience.