# For a Go slice, what is the difference between the slice and a full reslice of the slice?

Tags: arrays, go, copy, slice

Is there a difference between a slice and a full reslice of it?

given a slice `s:= make([]byte, 4, 4)`,
is there a difference between `copy(s[:], "data")` and `copy(s, "data")`?

Is there a case where these two lines will output different results?

Comment: You would never actually use `[:]` on a slice, assignment accomplishes the same thing. The `[:]` expression is used to convert an array to a slice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722542/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices in Go have 3 properties:

- The underlying array
- The length of the slice
- The capacity of the slice

`s` and `s[:]` will be identical with respect to all the above properties.

Go doesn't actually define an `==` operation for slices, but `s` and `s[:]` are equal in the sense that all measurable properties are the same.

The [`copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) function is only concerned with the first 2 properties, which are identical between `s` and `s[:]`.